# Convert Pine script v5 indicator to strategy for backtesting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When the indicator plots a shape to go long or short, I want to enter the market in that direction and exit market when opposite signal occurs.

```
plotshape(pl ? pl : na,"Pivot High",shape.labelup,location.absolute,max_color,-length,text="▲",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny) 
plotshape(ph ? ph : na,"Pivot Low",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,min_color,-length,text="▼",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
```

I have added 'strategy.entry' (see at bottom of code example) to enter market, but it enters in the wrong place. Not where the plotshape is displayed. Can someone assist?
Full code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Tops and Bottoms",overlay=true,max_bars_back=500,max_lines_count=500)
length = input.int(14,minval=2,maxval=500)

max_color = input.color(color.teal,'Trailing Maximum Color',group='Style')
min_color = input.color(color.red,'Trailing Minimum Color',group='Style')
avg_color = input.color(#ff5d00,'Trailing Maximum Color',group='Style')

bull_fill = input.color(color.new(color.teal,80),'Uptrend Area',group='Style')
bear_fill = input.color(color.new(color.red,80),'Downtrend Area',group='Style')
//----
var max = 0.
var min = 0.

ph = ta.pivothigh(length,length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(length,length)

if ph or pl
    max := high[length]
    min := low[length]

max := math.max(high[length],max)
min := math.min(low[length],min)

avg = math.avg(max,min)

//----
plot1 = plot(max,'Trailing Maximum',ph or pl ? na : max_color,1,plot.style_linebr,offset=-length)
plot2 = plot(min,'Trailing Minimum',ph or pl ? na : min_color,1,plot.style_linebr,offset=-length)

fill_css = fixnan(ph ? bear_fill : pl ? bull_fill : na)
fill(plot1,plot2,ph or pl ? na : fill_css)

plot(avg,'Average',ph or pl ? na : avg_color,1,plot.style_linebr,offset=-length)

plotshape(pl ? pl : na,"Pivot High",shape.labelup,location.absolute,max_color,-length,text="▲",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(ph ? ph : na,"Pivot Low",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,min_color,-length,text="▼",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)

//----
n = bar_index

max_prev = max
min_prev = min
avg_prev = avg
max2 = max
min2 = min

if barstate.islast
    for line_object in line.all
        line.delete(line_object)

    for i = 0 to length-1
        max2 := math.max(high[length-1-i],max_prev)
        min2 := math.min(low[length-1-i],min_prev)
        avg2 = math.avg(max2,min2)
        
        line1 = line.new(n-(length-i),max_prev,n-(length-1-i),max2,color=max_color)
        line2 = line.new(n-(length-i),min_prev,n-(length-1-i),min2,color=min_color)
        linefill.new(line1,line2,color.new(fill_css,80))
        
        line.new(n-(length-i),avg_prev,n-(length-1-i),avg2,color=avg_color)
        
        max_prev := max2
        min_prev := min2
        avg_prev := avg2

if ph 
    strategy.entry(id="Buy",direction=strategy.long)

if pl
    strategy.entry(id="Sell",direction=strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your signal is plotted with a delay : when the signal is ok to plot, your plot goes back 'length' bar (see the -length in the plot command) to plot the shape length bar before.
So you can't know before 'length' bars when you should have take your entry.
That's why your entry appears 'length' bar after your signal.